# Reducibility of a cubic over a number field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Given an extension $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ by a cubic polynomial $g(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (not necessarily Galois extension) is there a criterion for a cubic polynomial $f(x) \in K[x]$ to be reducible (f is actually defined over $\mathbb{Q}$)? I have tried assuming that $\beta$ is a root of $f$ then writing $\beta=a_{0}+a_{1}\alpha+a_{2}\alpha^2$ where $a_{i}\in \mathbb{Q}$ and substituting $\beta$ back into $f$ and equating the result to zero but I get a horrible equation to try and solve. (Essentially I want to find out when $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$, where $f(x)=x^3+6ax^2+9a^2x+27(3b-n)^2+4a^3$ and $g(x)=x^3-12ax^2+36a^2x+27(3b-n)^2+4a^3$ with $a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: One condition is that the two polynomials have the same discriminant. Is that a manageable equation for your f, g?

Comment: Two cubics can have the same discriminant but generate non-isomorphic fields though?

Comment: Do you want $f(x)$ to be irreducible over $\mathbf Q$? A necessary condition for two irreducible polynomials to each have a root that generates isomorphic field extensions of $\mathbf Q$ is that the discriminants of the polynomials have a *square ratio* (need not be equal). The condition is *not* sufficient. Irreducible cubics can have equal discriminant while their roots generate nonisomorphic extensions.

Comment: Hi @KConrad! Yes I am assuming that f is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and I think your answer will solve my problem so thank you!

Comment: Sorry, yes. I should have said exactly what Conrad did say.

Comment: @Asvin thanks for the help anyway!